# Can I specify multiple data targets for Twitter Bootstrap collapse?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'd like to target two divs for expand when clicking on a single trigger? Is that possible?

Answer (score 73):

You can simply add all the ids separated by commas in `data-target`:

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo,#demo1,#demo2">
  Hide them all
</button>
```

Comment: While this approach works very well, you will run into issues if a second button targets any of those ids.  Rather than the second button showing e.g. #demo, #demo3, it will hide #demo, and add #demo3 to the list shown.

Comment: I think class would be better than this solution.

Comment: This may not fully work.  Bootstrap.js is expecting just one id.  See bootstrap.js line 551 or so (depending on your version).  this.$trigger is set to whichever element has the element to show referenced in the data-target attribute.

Comment: Bootstrap3: The data-target attribute accepts a CSS selector to apply the collapse to (https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#via-data-attributes-3)

Comment: I am using Bootstrap 4.1.2, the solution does not work, it only target the latter id, ignoring the first id.

Answer (score 35):

Use the same class for both div's and set your `data-target` according this. Give your div's also the same parent (can also be a class) and set `data-parent` according this.

```
<button type="button" data-parent="#wrap" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".demo">
    simple collapsible
</button>
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="demo collapse">
        test1
    </div>
    <div class="demo collapse">
        test1
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: exact copy/paste from the Bootstrap source code:

value: function _getTargetFromElement(element) {
          var selector = _Util['default'].getSelectorFromElement(element);
          return selector ? $(selector)[0] : null;
        }

so, your solution will not work at all.

Answer (score 20):

From the [Bootstrap 3 documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#via-data-attributes-3):

> The data-target attribute accepts a CSS selector to apply the collapse to.

Therefore you can use a comma-separated list of id's, class selector etc. for the `data-target` attribute value:

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary"
        type="button"
        data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target="#target1,#target2,#target3"
        aria-expanded="false"
        aria-controls="target1,target2,target3">
```

You can see an extensive list of valid CSS selectors on the [w3schools website](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Comment: Do you have solution for Bootstrap 4?

Comment: @AndrewLam This should work for Bootstrap 4 as well. The [official documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/collapse/#multiple-targets) states: A `<button>` or `<a>` can show and hide multiple elements by referencing them with a JQuery selector in its `href` or `data-target` attribute. Perhaps you could try specifying a class instead of multiple ids?

Answer (score 7):

If you want to hide one element and show another (like the bootstrap accordion but without a panel) you can add multiple targets but also add the class 'in' to have one element expanded on load!

```
<div class="collapse text-center clearfix in" id="section1">
   <h1>This is section 1</h1>
   <p>Are you excited about toggling?</p>
</div>
<div class="collapse text-center clearfix alert-warning" id="section2">
   <h1>Boo!!</h1>
   <p>This is a new sentence</p>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-block btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#section1,#section2">Toggle</button>
```

[Live demo here](http://www.bootply.com/9qzmtbp6B8)

Answer (score 5):

There is a solution *in* Bootstrap 4:

[Bootstrap 4 documentation: Multiple targets](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#multiple-targets)

The least you need is:

- `data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".multi-collapse"` for the toggle
  button
- `class="collapse multi-collapse"` for each element you need to
  toggle

(While multiple ids in `data-target` indeed don't work).

Comment: This seems to be the only answer that works on this page. I tested it using classes in both JavaScript and as data targets.  I needed this as I was generating code in loops in VueJS and the ids (now classes) were bound to the indexes. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The data-target answer did not work for me. However you can use JavaScript to do this.

Make your button call some JavaScript like:

```
$('.collapse-class').collapse('toggle')
```

See: https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#via-javascript-3.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 4 uses document.querySelector instead of document.querySelectorAll. If this changes, then everything works.

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap 4 using the same *class* for each respective div seemed to work over using *id*.

```html
<button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".collapse-group">
                Reveal Items</button>
<div class="row">
                
  <h3>Visible Row div 1</h3>
    <div class="collapse-group collapse">
     <p>hidden item</p> 
    </div>
  <h3>div 2</h3>
  <div class="collapse-group collapse">
      <p>hidden item 2</p>  
    </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I  faced the same problem but bootstrap won't let  `data-toggle="tab"` beside `data-toggle="collapsed"` so my problem was like this.

I have:

```
<a type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block " href="#ld-tab-pane-eye" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="ld-tab-pane-eye" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style=" border: 0px ;"> </a>
```

and this was switching tabs:

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed nav-trigger style-mobile" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-header-collapse" aria-expanded="false" data-changeclassnames='{ "html": "mobile-nav-activated overflow-hidden" }'>
</button>
```

But this one closes the modal because the switch tab button was in the modal.

To solve the problem I add `id="popout"`(to first button) and `id="popoutTrigger"` (to secend button).

And this script (jQuery):

```
$( "#popout" ).click(function() {
  $( "#popoutTrigger" ).trigger( "click" );
});
```

When the user clicked the switch button in the modal, after switching modal will close.

This a view of what I've done.

[image: this a view of what I've done]

I hope my solution will help.

Answer (score 0):

Not in bootstrap 3.0.3, I have checked all combinations....