# How to make a tabs navigation with an "All" tab in Angular and Bootstrap?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-tabs

I am using Bootstrap and Angular and I have the following HTML:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-target="#" data-toggle="tab">All</a></li>
    <li><a data-target="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-target="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane active">Yeahhh, this is Tab 1.</div>
  <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane active">Yup, yup, this is Tab 2.</div>
</div>
```

I want to visualize both **#tab1** and **#tab2** when the "All" tab is clicked. How do I achieve this with Bootstrap and Angular?

Comment: [Angular Bootstrap UI](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs) can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20339507/2419808).

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-target=".tab-pane" data-toggle="tab">All</a></li>
    <li><a data-target="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-target="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane active">Yeahhh, this is Tab 1.</div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane active">Yup, yup, this is Tab 2.</div>
</div>
```

I just set the data-target of the "All" tab to a CSS class, that is present in all of my tabs. It doesn't have to be exactly 'tab-pane', you can use your own class - 'foo' or 'bar'. It's a nice and simple solution, as no external libraries are required to achieve this.