# Bootstrap collapse data-target selector fails

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have been trying to collapse multiple targets on a single click. According to Bootstrap documentation, this can be achieved by specifying matching CSS selector with the data-target attribute. However, the collapse seems to work only at the first element matching to the selector. Minimal example here:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://npmcdn.com/tether@1.2.4/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="device-icon-wrapper" data-toggle ="collapse" data-target=".Centrifuge2-collapsible">Collapse</div>
  <div class="col properties collapse Centrifuge2-collapsible">Properties</div>
  <div class="features Centrifuge2-collapsible collapse">Features</div>
</body>
```

If I remove or edit the class "Centrifuge2-collapsible" on the first collapsible div, the second div will become collapsible.

Can Bootstrap collapse target multiple elements? According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20339239/can-i-specify-multiple-data-targets-for-twitter-bootstrap-collapse) answer, it should be possible. However, multiple IDs also failed in this case.

Comment: Your example works in Bootply when the settings reflect running Bootstrap 4.0-beta.  Is it possible that your using the Alpha version is the issue?

Comment: Indeed, this solved the issue. Would you like to turn this to an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I'd probably just delete the question. Given that the answer was "Use the most recent version" there isn't much value in the question remaining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed by Robert C, this was an issue of the 4.0.0 alpha version and was solved already in the beta version. Updating the Bootstrap version solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

why not wrapping all your items in one container...

```html
<!doctype html>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://npmcdn.com/tether@1.2.4/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">


  <div class="device-icon-wrapper" data-toggle ="collapse" data-target=".Centrifuge2-collapsible">Collapse</div>
  <div class="Centrifuge2-collapsible collapse">
  <div class="col properties">Properties</div>
  <div class="features">Features</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This is not really an option in this case when the containers are disconnected and at different parts of the page. Of course, in the minimal example this could be a valid option.